# Rails Single-Table Inheritance (STI): dependencies on the derived models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

I'm about to use STI in my Rails 2.3 application.

I've modeled it the following way:

**Base Class:**

```
class Tariff < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.inherited(child)
    child.instance_eval do
      def model_name
        Tariff.model_name
      end
    end
    super
  end

  def self.select_options
    descendants.map { |c| c.to_s }.sort
  end
end
```

**Its subclasses:**

```
class FlatRateTariff < Tariff
end

class TimeOfUseTariff  < Tariff
  has_many :tariffing_periods, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tariffing_periods, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

When I am trying to create a **form_for :tariff** I'm getting an **undefined method `tariffing_periods' for Tariff**.  How should I go about modeling this scenario?  Should I put has_many association on the parent class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STI is usually done in Rails like this:

```
class Tariff < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class FlatRateTariff < Tariff
end

class TimeOfUseTariff < Tariff
end
```

**Make sure that the Tariff table has an attribute `type:string`** - that's where ActiveRecord stored the class name

You don't need this: (instead you can check **.class** )

```
 def self.inherited(child)
    child.instance_eval do
      def model_name
        Tariff.model_name
      end
    end
    super
  end
```

here's more info:

page 373 in Agile Web Development with Rails, 3rd edition

or: 
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780132480345/advanced-active-record/ch09lev1sec5

Comment: Thanks for pointing, I'm relying on IDE for correcting those ones.  Yet, the STI issue remains...

Comment: Yep I do have the type attribute of cause.  I did removed the "inherited" helper method, thanks.  Yet still when I do form_for :tariff it complains about undefined tariffing_periods method, which I have on the subclass of Tariff...  Which kind of makes sense because ActiveRecord doesn't know as yet which subclass of Tariff I am creating. Yet still I don't know how to go about it....